Why does Windows leave 1 sector gaps between partitions?
I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Arch Linux. Running gdisk on Arch Linux on the disk on which Windows is installed yields these results:
Command (? for help): p
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1               2048         1085438   529.0 MiB   0700  
2            1085440         1863538   379.9 MiB   EF00  
3            1863540       517124974   245.7 GiB   0700

As you can see, sectors 1085439 and 1863539 are unused. These partitions were created by the Windows setup program. Is there a limitation in NTFS or FAT32 that the filesystem cannot end on odd sectors?
There is no issue with 512-byte gaps existing between partitions, but I want to know if I should leave gaps myself when I modify or create partitions in Linux, or if Windows won't care either way. Since partitions end on an even sector, this means that they can never have a "nice" size (they cannot be divided by 1 KiB), so that's also kind of annoying.

Helpful to know the model and manufacturer of the disk in question

@Ramhound Samsung 860 EVO SSD (1TB)

512 byte 4096 logical sector size for anyone wondering. I am unable to reproduce with my own Samsung SSDs.

Where did you get that information? All tools I used (gdisk, hdparm, lsblk, /sys/class/block/sda/queue/ and even smartctl) tell me that I have 512/512.

Possibly due to an effort to create a "guardrail" between partitions? The idea is to preemptively avoid a catastrophic overwrite due to a (sector number) miscalculation by an "off by 1" type of error. Back in the day of CHS adressing, I've seen an entire cylinder wasted (per partition) due to such preventative measure in a version of Unix. FWIW GParted does not normally create such separation between partitions, unless it's due to start alignment.

@DarkAtom - I searched for the specification of the drive.

These partitions were created by the Windows setup program. From their size and the location, I highly doubt that it is true. I mean, at least not "orthodox" Windows Setup in a usual/official ISO. (And FWIW, there is no related limitation in Windows and Linux.)
